# Como concatenar duas strings e salvar o resultado em uma variável?

Tags: php, json

Estou usando uma *API* para capturar *proxies*. Ela me retorna os *proxies* no formato *JSON*, da seguinte maneira:

```
{
    "_links": {
        "_self": "\ / proxy",
        "_parent": "\ /"
    },
    "ip": "45.55.23.78",
    "porto": 1080,
    "protocolo": "socks5",
    "anonimato": "alto anonimato",
    "LastTested": "2018-03-09 06:51:27",
    "permiteRefererHeader": true
    "permiteUserAgentHeader": true
    "permiteCustomHeaders": true,
    "permiteCookies": true
    "permitePost": verdadeiro,
    "permiteHttps": true
    "país": "EUA",
    "connectTime": "0.721",
    "downloadSpeed": "160,000",
    "secondsToFirstByte": "1.079",
    "tempo de atividade": "99.164"
}
```

Eu quero pegar apenas o *IP* e a *porta*, mas preciso juntar os dois pra ficar dessa forma o resultado: *45.55.23.78:1080*.

Eu estava capturando dessa forma:

```
$f = file_get_contents("link da minha api");
$json = json_decode($f);
 $proxy = $json->ip;
 $porta = $json->port;
```

Só que eu preciso que os dois fique em apenas uma variável, por exemplo `$ipPort = $json->ip:port`. È apenas um exemplo, não sei como fazer isso por isso, preciso da ajuda de vocês.

Comment: É possível fazer também da seguinte maneira: `$proxy = "{$json->ip}:{$json->port}";` **ou** `sprintf("%s:%s", $json->ip, $json->port);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme seu exemplo:

```
 $proxy = $json->ip;
 $porta = $json->port;  

 $full = $json->ip.":".$json->port;
 echo $full;
```

resultado:

> 127.0.0.1:80

Comment: Já tinha conseguido, fiz dessa forma ai mesmo, obg por tentar ajudar !